# Clarification on equations and terminology of characteristic curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am currently studying the textbook *Partial Differential Equations – An introduction*, second edition, by Walter A. Strauss. The section **The Variable Coefficient Equation** of chapter 1 says the following:

> The equation
> $$u_x + y u_y = 0 \label{4}\tag{4}$$
> is linear and homogeneous but has a variable coefficient ($y$). We shall illustrate for equation \eqref{4} how to use the geometric method somewhat like Example 1. The PDE \eqref{4}  itself asserts that *the directional derivative in the direction of the vector $(1, y)$ is zero*. The curves in the $xy$ plane with $(1, y)$ as tangent vectors have slopes $y$ (see Figure 3). Their equations are
> $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{1} \label{5}\tag{5}$$
> This ODE has the solutions
> $$y = Ce^x \label{6}\tag{6}$$
> These curves are called the *characteristic curves* of the PDE \eqref{4} . As $C$ is changed, the curves fill out the $xy$ plane perfectly without intersecting. On each of the curves $u(x, y)$ is a constant because
> $$\dfrac{d}{dx}u(x, Ce^x) = \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} + Ce^x \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = u_x + yu_y = 0.$$
> [image]

**Example 3.** then says the following:

> Solve the PDE
> $$u_x + 2xy^2 u_y = 0. \tag{8}$$
> The characteristic curves satisfy the ODE $dy/dx = 2xy^2/1 = 2xy^2$. To solve the ODE, we separate variables: $dy/y^2 = 2x \ dx$; hence $-1/y = x^2 - C$, so that
> $$y = (C - x^2)^{-1}$$
> These curves are characteristics. Again $u(x, y)$ is a constant on each curve.

This seems like it's poorly written, so I'm a bit confused with the terminology here. At the beginning, the author seems to say that the curves (characteristic curves?) have equations $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{1}$ (not $y = Ce^x$?). Then, for example 3, the author says that the characteristics (characteristic curves?) have equations $y = (C - x^2)^{-1}$; but it seems to me that this corresponds with $y = Ce^x$, not $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{1}$. So what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *curve* is just a general terminology. Usually there is a simple explicit parametric representation $(x(t),y(t))$ or as given in the examples here an explicit representation in the form $(x,y(x))$.

Note, that the curves are not given in either forms at first but rather described via ODE equations. Those needed to be solved at first to get explicit representations.

Furthermore, a *characteristic* curve has another property: the solution $u=u(x,y)$ is constant on that specific curve.

---

Just to be sure. I think what confused you might be the part "Their equations are $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{1}$ ...". That is just saying that the curves are described by solutions to that specific ODE.

Comment: So "characteristics" and "characteristic curves" are the same thing?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes.

Comment: So what is the connection between $y = Ce^x$ and $y = (C - x^2)^{-1}$, because doesn't the author suggest that these are both characteristic curves?

Comment: but to different PDEs